# Prestashop - show video only on certain products

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I am trying to write a code that will show  of video on certain products and on other products it will show another `<iframe>`.

I've got this far:

```
{if $id_product = 39}<iframe width="800" height="400"       src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EXAMPLE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>{/if}
```

and for other products i am using the same code but changing the product id. I think the variable of product id is bad, but i cannot find the right one. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help-how-to-ask and then look at your question again. As you will perhaps realise, it is just about impossible for enyone to help you with this question without more information about how you are using it

Comment: It depends on many things. How many products with video and how many products with iframe?  What is the relationship between your video and your product? 1:1 or n:1? the same question apply to relationship between product and iframe for second group of products if any. Depending on the answer, maybe you will need a custom field in your product entity and/or column/table in database. Please to explain more. Anyways comparing to constant values like 39 is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`{if $id_product == 39}`

Where == tests if equal while = means assignment.

That being said it seems you are adding this into a template file so unless you specifically assigned $id_product as a smarty variable, this doesn't exist.

Depending on the template, you should try with $product.id or $product->id or $product['id'].

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to tell us which version of PrestaShop you use and where you want to display this video?

1. PrestaShop 1.6 and product list:

`{if $product.id_product == ID_OF_THE_PRODUCT}here's your code{/if}`

2. PrestaShop 1.6, product page:

`{if $product->id == ID_OF_THE_PRODUCT}here's your code{/if}`

3. PrestaShop 1.7 product page and product list:

`{if $product.id_product == ID_OF_THE_PRODUCT}here's your code{/if}`